# if ( val = val ) not working! never gets in if block

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, equals

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ' Datatable ADD COLUMN NAMES
    table1.Columns.Add(" ÜRÜN CİNSİ", GetType(String))
    table1.Columns.Add("STOK KODU", GetType(String))
    table1.Columns.Add("BİRİM FİYAT/KG", GetType(Integer))
    table1.Columns.Add("KDV ORANI", GetType(Integer))

    ' DAtatable ADD ROWS 
    table1.Rows.Add("ERİK", "Y-9532", 1250, 6)
    table1.Rows.Add("KİRAZ", "Z-1250", 1500, 8)
    table1.Rows.Add("ÇİLEK", "H-2548", 2000, 8)

    'ADD TO combobox
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("ERİK")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("KİRAZ")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("ÇİLEK")

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)


    Dim Table_ndx As Integer

    For index = 0 To ComboBox1.Items.Count

        If (ComboBox1.SelectedItem == table1.Rows(index)(0)) Then

            Table_ndx = index
        End If
    Next

    Me.Text = Table_ndx.ToString

    lbl0_stok_kodu.Text = table1.Rows(Table_ndx)(1)  'stkkodu
    tb1_birim_kg.Text = table1.Rows(Table_ndx)(2)  'birim kg
    tb2_kdv_orani.Text = table1.Rows(Table_ndx)(3)  'kdv oranı
```

This **"Table_ndx"** always comes ZERO because, it doesn't get in if  block

I have already had items in combobox 
and have loaded them in datatable too

**update** i changed it to single =  but code runs BUT still 
 **Table_ndx  is equal ZERO**

Comment: VB equality operator is `=`

Comment: Most likely, because `ComboBox1.SelectedItem` and `table1.Rows(index)(0)` are both of type `Object`, it is probably comparing object references rather than their values.  You might try `If (ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() = table1.Rows(index)(0).ToString()) Then` or `If (DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, String) = DirectCast(table1.Rows(index)(0), String)) Then` and see if either of them works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is twofold.  First, as has been pointed out, your comparison should be

```
If (ComboBox1.SelectedItem = table1.Rows(index)(0)) Then
```

Second, you have no error checking, if you did, you would find out that iterating from 0 to Items.Count goes from 0 to 3.  There is no index of 3 in your data table, so the code bombs out and it never hits the rest of your code.  Change that to the following...

```
For index = 0 To ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1
```

Always remember that VB.NET uses 0-based indexing, so you only ever iterate to MaxArraySize - 1.

Answer (score 1):

VB.NET doesn't know what `==` is.

Should be: (assuming your combox contains the object as the table1.Rows(0)(index)

```
 If (ComboBox1.SelectedItem = table1.Rows(index)(0)) Then 
   ...
 End If
```

Comment: (0)(index) should be reversed.  Otherwise you will always get the first row and column index.